# views and contextual filter with entity reference to current user

Tags: entities, views

I have a view that I need to filter based on the current logged in user, however a secondary entity reference is in-between the two.  Pretty sure I need to add in PHP contextual filter code but not exactly sure what is needed.

Scenario:

1. inventory has an entity reference to retail_location.
2. retail_location has an entity reference to users.
3. I need to display inventory based on the retail_location of the logged in user.

D7.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get it working using the following code, it does however only allow for one retail location, which is all I need for this scenario.

```
  global $user;
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'rnm_principal')
      ->fieldCondition('field_principal_retailer', 'target_id', array($user->uid));
  $results = $query->execute();
  return current($results['node'])->nid;
```